# How do I change my link's image on click?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code that allows for a user to hover over an image and it will display a new image (well, a new section of a sprite image).  I want it to display a third image on click.  1.  Am i doing this the most efficient way?  2. How do I code for an on-click image to show up?

HTML:

```
<a href="<?php echo base_url('home/linkedin_login')?>" ><img style = "border-radius: 5px;" class="signin-all" src="assets/images/header/blank.png"></a>
```

CSS:

```
    [class^="signin-"] {
  display: inline-block;

  vertical-align: text-top;
  background-image: url('../images/signin_sprite.jpg');

  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  *margin-right: .3em;
}
[class^="signin-"]:last-child {
  *margin-left: 0;
}
.signin-all{
background-position: 0px 0px;
   width: 132px;
  height: 37px;
  position: absolute;
}
.signin-all:hover{
background-position: 0px -34px;
   width: 132px;
  height: 34px;
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Daniel, you should accept some of your prior questions' answers.

Comment: Read the faq: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need JavaScript to solve this.

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="changeImage()">
    <img style = "border-radius: 5px;" class="signin-all" src="assets/images/header/blank.png" id="image">
</a>

<script>
    function changeImage() {
        document.getElementById("image").src="newImageSource";
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Hmm this doesn't work for me I tried: <img style = "border-radius: 5px;" class="signin-all"  onclick="changeImage()" src="assets/images/header/blank.png" id="image">  with the javascript: (in script tags)  function changeImage() {
        document.getElementById("image").src="assets/uploads/13431777491_2144482096395_2018984525_n.jpg";
    }

Comment: I added an "a" tag so you can click. Try that now.